# Omit base package directory structure in Maven

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to omit the base package from the directory structure in Maven?

For example let's say we have a project with a base package `org.example.server` with 2 files :

```
Main.java (package: org.example.server)
Other.java (package: org.example.server.modules)
```

I want them to have the following locations in my project

```
src/main/java/Main.java
src/main/java/modules/Other.java
```

And the final Jar should be identical as if these files were placed according to the standard layout

```
org/example/server/Main.class
org/example/server/modules/Other.class
```

Comment: Java requires files to be in a directory structure that matches their package name. How would you in your case distinct between `foo.Main` and `bar.Main`?

Comment: Or maybe put differently: What is your use case, considering that every IDE should be capable of hiding common base packages?

Comment: @Marvin if I am not mistaken Java only cares about the structure inside the jar. I don't have a problem (in fact I want them to) for the files to be in their package directories in the final output. I just want them without the deep common folder in the source.

Comment: @Marvin yes, inside the IDE they are collapsed but many times I have to navigate to these folders from command line. It's not critical, just personal preference

Comment: The directory structure starting from `src/main/java/<packageName>` defined the package names within the resulting jar file and so in consequence you have to define the directories as the package structure or in other words the directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Each package must be in a directory of the same name. It is a requirement of the language implementation for both compilation and execution, rather than an issue with Maven.

While the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.2) doesn't prevent some implementation to work differently I'm not aware of any and it would remain to be seen if it would be compatible with Maven.